# Database for drug-target relation

Tags: pharmacology, database

I'm writing a thesis on bioinformatics and looking for drug-target databases. I'm implementing a open-source application for a tool called Cytoscape and so far I've used a open-source database called [DrugBank](https://www.drugbank.ca/) to retrieve drug-target data, but I've read a paper on a database called Drug2Gene that combines multiple open databases into a unified format. The paper is from 2014, but all websites are down and I was wondering if someone here knows of any other databases/resources that does this and is maybe up-to-date? I want to utilize as much open-source data on drug to target relation as possible to provide a simple way of accessing all these resources. Drugbank is regularly updated and a good source, but with so many different databases with a decreasing overlap of data I was happy to stumble across Drug2Gene database only to realize I can't get it and it's probably not up-to-date.

I will be very thankful for any tips as I'm purely a Informatician and feeling helpless in finding thing related to biology.

Source: [Drug2Gene paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24618344)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a lot drug databases. I think **DGIbd** is a good place to start (see below). Further there are a lot of databases which describe drugs and their targets, take a look at these (and the links at the bottom) hopefully you can use several of these in your implementation.

**SIDER**

> [SIDER](http://sideeffects.embl.de/) contains information on marketed medicines and their recorded
>   adverse drug reactions. The information is extracted from public
>   documents and package inserts. The available information include side
>   effect frequency, drug and side effect classifications as well as
>   links to further information, for example drug–target relations.

---

**DrugCentral**

> [DrugCentral](http://drugcentral.org/about) provides information on active ingredients chemical
>   entities, pharmaceutical products, drug mode of action, indications,
>   pharmacologic action. We monitor FDA, EMA, and PMDA for new drug
>   approval on regular basis to ensure currency of the resource. Limited
>   information on discontinued and drugs approved outside US is also
>   available however regulatory approval information can't be verified.

---

**Therapeutic Target Database**

> [Therapeutic Target Database (TTD)](http://bidd.nus.edu.sg/group/cjttd/) is a database to provide information
>   about the known and explored therapeutic protein and nucleic acid
>   targets, the targeted disease, pathway information and the
>   corresponding drugs directed at each of these targets. Also included
>   in this database are links to relevant databases containing
>   information about target function, sequence, 3D structure, ligand
>   binding properties, enzyme nomenclature and drug structure,
>   therapeutic class, clinical development status. All information
>   provided are fully referenced.

---

**Potential drug target database (PDTD)**
*NOTE: I think this one is coupled to DrugBank however you can take a look here*

> [PDTD](http://www.dddc.ac.cn/pdtd/) is a dual function database that associates an informatics
>   database to a structural database of known and potential drug targets.
>   PDTD is a comprehensive, web-accessible database of drug targets, and
>   focuses on those drug targets with known 3D-structures.

---

**PharmGKB**

> [The PharmGKB](https://www.pharmgkb.org/aboutUs.jsp) is a pharmacogenomics knowledge resource that encompasses
>   clinical information including dosing guidelines and drug labels,
>   potentially clinically actionable gene-drug associations and
>   genotype-phenotype relationships. PharmGKB collects, curates and
>   disseminates knowledge about the impact of human genetic variation on
>   drug responses through the following activities: Annotate genetic
>   variants and gene-drug-disease relationships via literature reviews
>   Summarize important pharmacogenomic genes, associations between
>   genetic variants and drugs, and drug pathways Curate FDA drug labels
>   containing pharmacogenomic information Enable consortia examining
>   important questions in pharmacogenomics Curate and participate in
>   writing pharmacogenomic-based drug dosing guidelines Contribute to
>   clinical implementation projects for pharmacogenomics through
>   collaborations Publish pharmacogenomic-based drug dosing guidelines,
>   very important pharmacogene summaries and drug-centered pathways
>   Display all information on the website and provide comprehensive
>   downloads

---

**STITCH**

> To facilitate access to this data, [STITCH](http://stitch.embl.de/) (‘search tool for
>   interactions of chemicals’) integrates information about interactions
>   from metabolic pathways, crystal structures, binding experiments and
>   drug–target relationships. Inferred information from phenotypic
>   effects, text mining and chemical structure similarity is used to
>   predict relations between chemicals. STITCH further allows exploring
>   the network of chemical relations, also in the context of associated
>   binding proteins. Each proposed interaction can be traced back to the
>   original data sources. Our database contains interaction information
>   for over 68 000 different chemicals, including 2200 drugs, and
>   connects them to 1.5 million genes across 373 genomes and their
>   interactions contained in the STRING database.

---

**SuperTarget and Metador**

> An easy-to-use query interface enables the user to pose complex
>   queries, for example to find drugs that target a certain pathway,
>   interacting drugs that are metabolized by the same cytochrome P450 or
>   drugs that target the same protein but are metabolized by different
>   enzymes. Furthermore, we provide tools for 2D drug screening and
>   sequence comparison of the targets. The database contains more than
>   2500 target proteins, which are annotated with about 7300 relations to
>   1500 drugs; the vast majority of entries have pointers to the
>   respective literature source. A subset of these drugs has been
>   annotated with additional binding information and indirect
>   interactions and is available as a separate resource called [Matador.](http://insilico.charite.de/supertarget/index.php?site=targets)

---

**Pharos**

> [Pharos](https://pharos.nih.gov/idg/about) is the user interface to the Knowledge Management Center (KMC)
>   for the Illuminating the Druggable Genome (IDG) program funded by the
>   National Institutes of Health (NIH) Common Fund. (Grant No.
>   5U54CA189205-02). The goal of KMC is to develop a comprehensive,
>   integrated knowledge-base for the Druggable Genome (DG) to illuminate
>   the uncharacterized and/or poorly annotated portion of the DG,
>   focusing on four of the most commonly drug-targeted protein families:
>    G-protein-coupled receptors (GPCRs); nuclear receptors (NRs); ion
>   channels (ICs); and kinases. For more information on opportunities in
>   the druggable human genome see this poster

---

**KEGG drug**

> [KEGG DRUG](http://www.genome.jp/kegg/drug/) is a comprehensive drug information resource for approved
>   drugs in Japan, USA, and Europe unified based on the chemical
>   structures and/or the chemical components, and associated with target,
>   metabolizing enzyme, and other molecular interaction network
>   information. All the marketed drugs in Japan, not only the
>   prescription drugs but also the OTC drugs, are fully represented in
>   KEGG DRUG and integrated with the package insert information (labels
>   information). These include crude drugs and TCM (Tradictional Chinese
>   Medicine) drugs.

---

**The IUPHAR/BPS Guide to PHARMACOLOGY (database)**

> The information in [the database](http://www.guidetopharmacology.org/targets.jsp) is presented at two levels: the
>   initial view or landing pages for each target family provide
>   expert-curated overviews of the key properties and selective ligands
>   and tool compounds available. For selected targets more detailed
>   introductory chapters for each family are available along with curated
>   information on the pharmacological, physiological, structural, genetic
>   and pathophysiogical properties of each target. The database is
>   enhanced with hyperlinks to additional information in other databases
>   including Ensembl, UniProt, PubChem, ChEMBL and DrugBank, as well as
>   curated chemical information and literature citations in PubMed.

---

**DGIbd**

> The druggable genome can be defined as the genes or gene products that
>   are known or predicted to interact with drugs, ideally with a
>   therapeutic benefit to the patient. Such genes are of particular
>   interest to large-scale cancer profiling efforts such as TCGA, ICGC
>   and others that identify lists of potential cancer driver genes from
>   high-throughput sequence and other genome-wide data. In cancer
>   therapy, the increasing number of targeted drugs--those designed to
>   inactivate proteins carrying activating amino acid changes as
>   determined by mutational analyses--make more compelling the need for a
>   searchable database of drug-gene interactions, available [here](http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/search_interactions).

---

There are a lot more databases, maybe these links will help you:

- [Drug to Target/Gene/Protein Interaction Databases](https://www.biostars.org/p/17392/)
- [Question: Database Of Drugs Targeting Genes](https://www.biostars.org/p/18282/)
- [Drug Databases](https://www.drugbank.ca/w/databases)